# How to centre play button using Material UI and Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, material-ui

I am looking for some advice regarding this layout. I am struggling to get the play button in the middle with the borders. I have the following code so far, I am just struggling with getting flexbox to position the play button.

```
    function Tasks(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm container>
            <Grid item xs container direction="column" spacing={2}>
              <Grid item xs>
              <div className="name-label">
              Name
              </div>
              <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
              Order cofee beans
              </Typography>
              <div className="form-divider"></div>
                <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
                  Process of Description
                </Typography>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Typography variant="subtitle">Workers Assigned</Typography>
              <Grid item xs={3}>
        <i class="far fa-play-circle"></i>
      </Grid>
              <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
              0/25</Typography>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Currently, I am unsure if the Grid is the issue or if I need to better structure what I have, any feedback would be much appreciated. I have an image of what it should look like:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfqfi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use flex to position the button like that. It looks like you'd want something like:

```js
const styles = theme => ({
  box1: {
    display: "flex",
    position: "relative",
    "& .playButton": {
      position: "absolute",
      top: "50%",
      transform: "translateY(-50%)"
    }
  }
});

const YourComponent = props => (
  <div>
    {...}
    <Grid item classes={{ root: props.classes.box1}}>
      <Typography variant="subtitle">Workers Assigned</Typography>
      <Grid item xs={3} className="playButton">
        <i class="far fa-play-circle"></i>
      </Grid>
      <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>0/25</Typography>
    </Grid>
    {...}
  </div>
);

YourComponent = withStyles(styles)(YourComponent);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I seem to have worked. I just need to sort out the rest of it now.